# ZFS Snapshot showing unreachable inside snapdir

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, zfs, zfsonlinux

I am using ZFS with Linux 3.19.0-58-generic. I have created some snapshots, but when I cd into these directories after one point it becomes unreachable, what does that mean ? Is there any workaround through which I can solve it.

Comment: Show the error message.

Comment: There is no error message it is just this when I cd into folder `shilpi@minions-gcp:(unreachable)/folder`

Comment: Can you post the output of:
"zfs list -t snapshot -r shilpi"

Comment: Please state the ZoL version you are running.

Comment: Does this only happen when a non-root user tries to cd into the snapshot directory after the root user has done so?